# react/c# - fetch to c# causes Ssl exception

Tags: c#, reactjs, ravendb

I perform the following query (sorry for the ill-written code).

```
(...)
    const res : boolean = await fetch("https://localhost:5001/api/v1/User/?" + new URLSearchParams({login: login, password: password, repeatedPassword: repeatedPassword}), {method: 'POST'})
(...)
```

for the c# webapi, that is connected to RavenDB.

I get the following exception:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unhandled exception while processing 0HM9Q57V1OER6.
System.IO.IOException: The encryption operation failed, see inner exception.
 ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: Operation failed with error - 5.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   (...)
```

What may I do with this? I have tried repeating the same query with Postman, it performs successfully.

Comment: 1. where's definition of `fetch`; 2. most probably your post parameters should be in body, not query strings.

Comment: The asp.net development server (Kestrel) is usually not set up to run https by default. Have you tried using http://localhost:5001 instead?

Comment: Are you using IIS or kestrel server? Also do u have any data in your response?

Comment: @LeiYang definition of fetch is provided above, and I am not sure this is the reason, nor the post parameters, get queries behave in the same way. What is more, the issue appeared only after I migrated the system from one virtual machine to another.

Comment: @JonasHøgh I have started with trying to replace http with https, as you see, it does nothing.

Comment: @DarshaniJayasekara Kestrel server, response returns text string.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18154

Comment: @DarshaniJayasekara yes, I have seen the issue, the problem is that this is a bit different issue to my own. Didn't help. the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is strange that this issue appeared. For me, the solution was to comment out the following string in `Program.cs`:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection()
```

should be

```
//app.UseHttpsRedirection()
```